# Add ref to a child div in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using a library.  When I call the component, it renders a Dom like:

```
<div class="marquee-container test">
  <div class="marquee" ref={needToAddRefHere}>
     <child />
     <child />
     <child />
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I don't have access to add a ref to that child .marquee div.  Only the parent .marquee-container.

How can I add a ref to it? Note: I need to add a forwardref starting on .marquee. Not the parent div.  I also don't have access to pass them down as props.

```
<Marquee className="test"/>
```

Comment: That isn't possible right? since all I'm calling is <Marquee />... how will I access prop?

Comment: You'll need to modify the `Marquee` component's code to do that. Why do you specifically need to ref on that `div`?

Comment: @juliomalves According to nextjs doc. When using a horizontal scroller, I need to add a ref directly to div with the scrolling div.  Which is the one with the class marquee. I don't see a fix for this though then...